# Mistletoe hat (in 2014 Winter Bash) and SE servers

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

I've just read [blog summary about ended 2014 Winter Bash](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/so-long-winter-bash-2014/?cb=1). One thing, that interested me, is:

> and Mistletoe (207 times to 154 users). Due to timezones, we were pretty generous with the timing. But not Mistletoe, which required chatting within a ten minute period around January 1, 2015 0000 UTC. Thankfully our chat servers handled the load just fine.

In particular:

1. If Mistletoe is awarded by *chatting within a ten minute period around January 1, 2015 0000 UTC*, then how can one person earn it more than once? Is it because if you're chatting (few tabs open) in more than one SE site, in that specific period of time, you were awarded by this hat on each SE sites on which you were active?
2. How should I understand "*Thankfully our chat servers handled the load just fine*" in compare to "*207 times to 154 users*"? Are SE servers "so weak", that 150+ users chatting at the same time can cause a server's serious overload threat? Or is it another SE-kind joke that I don't understand?

Comment: A user could earn it on multiple sites - for example I earned it on DBA and another site - one user, 2 hats.

Comment: +1 for the second point; first point was clarified by @blue.

Comment: I'm sure there were a lot more people trying to get the hat around that time whose messages weren't starred, plus those people certainly sent more than the 207 messages that did get a star. I think it's just about the fact, that there was probably *normal* activity on chat anyway *plus* an additional bunch of users trying to get the badge who wouldn't be chatting at all (or much less) if the badge wasn't a thing. But of course, that's only speculation. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Yes. Several people got the "hat" on several sites by jumping from one chat room to another.
2. I'll be honest: I wrote the blurb about Mistletoe before I looked at the data. My impression that lots of people were going after (and getting) the cosmetic item came largely from [the activity on Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89/2015/1/1). (Also occuring at about the same time: [this bug](https://twitter.com/GBrayUT/status/550455391084359680).) I suspect we actually had a little less chat traffic than we normally do ten minutes around 0000 UTC thanks to the holiday.

So, yeah. I probably ought to have worded that a bit differently. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Thanks for a great answer and honestly. Yes, I love to read in details and dig-out such "sniffy" things. BTW: Great _future developer_, you have there on your avatar! :> Cheers...

Comment: @trejder: No problem. I actually have my hopes that he will become a professional athlete and take care of me in my old age. ;-)

Comment: Why an athlete, Jon? If he'll become a developer, then senior developer and finally DEV team manager, company director or even owner, he'll have enough _money_ to take care of you in your old age and he doesn't have to become an athlete! :>